# Angular 2+ attach directive from component dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

I need to attach directive from component depending on some condition. 
I've tried to do this via @HostBinding like this, but it does not work

```
 import { Component, Directive, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
     <div>Test text</div>
   `
 })
 export class AppComponent  {
    @HostBinding('attr.appCustomDirective') directive;
 }

 @Directive({
   selector: '[appCustomDirective]'
 })
 export class CustomDirective {
   @HostBinding('style.color') color = 'red';
 }
```

I assume that I need to recompile template or something like this but I have no idea how to do this.

Will be really thankful for help!

[Code snippet on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbqu2g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

You have done almost everything correct, you just need to add your directive to the host element you want to apply the style. You can't add or remove directive dynamically(at-least for now) but one thing you can do is to disable or enable your directive via a `@Input()` variable and on the getter of the hostbinding you can check for that.

```
import { Component, Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, SimpleChange } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div appCustomDirective [enabled-directive]="isDirectiveEnabled">Test text</div>
        <button (click)="enableDirective()">Enable</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  isDirectiveEnabled: boolean;
  constructor() {
    this.isDirectiveEnabled = true;
  }

  @HostBinding('attr.appCustomDirective') directive;

  enableDirective() {
    this.isDirectiveEnabled = !this.isDirectiveEnabled;
  }
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomDirective]'
})
export class CustomDirective {
  @Input('enabled-directive') enabledDirective: boolean;
  @HostBinding('style.color') color : string;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const directiveState: SimpleChange = changes.enabledDirective;
    this.color = directiveState.currentValue ? 'red' : 'black';
  }


}
```

Have a look at the working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjkprc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks so much. I struggled with a similar issue for two days until I came across your answer.